# Use Stirling's formula to estimate the location and size of the largest term of the Taylor series of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Use Stirling's formula to estimate the location and size of the largest term of the Taylor series of $e^x$. I don't know how to start. Thanks

Comment: How to start: The $k$-th term is $x^k/k!$. Replace that by $x^k$ divided by the approximation to $k!$ you get from Stirling's formula, and then try to figure what value of $k$ maximizes _that_.

Comment: Or you can use prepackaged result about the mode of Poisson distribution (for $x>0$): $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for non-integer and botj $x$ and $x-1$, $x$ for integer $x$.

Comment: One could also use that the quotient from one term to the next is $a_{n+1}/a_n=x/(n+1)$ to see when it changes from being $>1$ to $<1$.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I kind of combined all of your ideas. I assume that the kth term is the largest one. And I replace k! with the stirling's formula. Then I evaluate (k-th/(k+1)-th) term and I get a formula, but then I have no idea how to find k.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Stirling approximation $$k!\approx \sqrt{2\pi k}\,\Big(\frac ke\Big)^k$$ you have $$A=\frac{x^k}{k!}\approx \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{2\pi k}\,\Big(\frac ke\Big)^k}$$ Consider that $k$ is continuous and compute the derivative with respect to $k$. This will give $$A'=-\frac{e^k k^{-k-\frac{3}{2}} x^k (-2 k \log (x)+2 k \log (k)+1)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$ and this will cancel for $$-2 k \log (x)+2 k \log (k)+1=0 \tag 1$$ the solution of which being explicitely given in terms of Lambert function $$k=-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2 x}\right)}$$ which is defined for $x \geq \frac e2$.

If you cannot use Lambert function, solve equation $(1)$ using Newton method, searching for the zero of $$f(k)=-2 k \log (x)+2 k \log (k)+1$$ $$f'(k)=2 (\log (k)-\log (x)+1)$$ and, starting from a "reasonable" guess $k_0$, the iterates will be given by $$k_{n+1}=k_n-\frac{f(k_n)}{f'(k_n)}$$

For illustration purposes, let us try using $x=10$ and, being very lazy, let us use $k_0=5$. The successive iterates will then be $$k_1=14.6650$$ $$k_2=10.2431$$ $$k_3=9.51457$$ $$k_4=9.48663$$  $$k_5=9.48659$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Let us check  $$\frac{10^7}{7!}\approx 1984.13$$ $$\frac{10^8}{8!}\approx 2480.16$$ $$\frac{10^9}{9!}\approx 2755.73$$ $$\frac{10^{10}}{10!}\approx 2755.73$$ $$\frac{10^{11}}{11!}\approx 2505.21$$ $$\frac{10^{12}}{12!}\approx 2087.68$$

Using Lambert function approximation for small $y$ $$W(y)=y-y^2+\frac{3 y^3}{2}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ would have given $W(\frac{-1}{20})\approx -\frac{843}{16000}$, $k\approx \frac{8000}{843}=9.48992$

**Edit**

I took a long way and, as the OP noticed, the solution is almost $k\approx x$. Using $$k=-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2 x}\right)}$$ and considering that $x$ is large, a Taylor expansion gives $$k=x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8 x}-\frac{1}{12 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$

In fact, if we simply consider $$f(k)=-2 k \log (x)+2 k \log (k)+1$$ we can notice that $f(x)=1$ and that $$f(x-1)=2 (x-1) \log (x-1)-2 (x-1) \log (x)+1$$ is always negative as soon as $x \geq \frac e2$.

Comment: I am lost when you plug in x=10 and k_0=5. And I don't understand what your conclusion means. Aren't we supposed to find the location and size of the largest term? I don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: I showed that you need to solve $-2 k \log (x)+2 k \log (k)+1=0 $ to get the location of the maximum. I am just using Newton method for $x=10$ starting iterations at $k_0=5$.

Comment: Is the answer that the location of the maximum is when n=x?

Comment: I still have questions: How'd you know that k5 is the solution? Does that mean when n=5, we get the maximum? But after that when you check, you start from n=7. I am kinda confused. Thanks

Comment: @J.doe. $k_5$ is the last iterate of Newton procedure for six significant figures. If you look at the equation $-2 k \log (x)+2 k \log (k)+1=0$, for sure the solution $k$ is "close" to $x$.

Comment: Oh I get it! But when you checked your answer, you start from n=7, why is that? thanks a lot!

Comment: If we look at that equation and if k is "close" to x, isn't the result of that equation is closer to 1? since -2klog(x)+2klog(k) is close to 0 when k is close to x?

Comment: @J.doe. You are right : if we use Newton with $k_0=x$, the first iterate is $k_1=x-\frac 12$

Comment: So the answer would be when kn is closest to x, we get our location of the maximum, which is the n-th term?

Comment: @J.doe. You are totally correct and I took a too long way. Look at my edit.

Comment: If k ≈ x, then isn't the equation −2klog(x)+2klog(k)+1= 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @J.doe. The equation does not change (it is the derivative). But, the solution is $k\approx x-\frac 12$.

Comment: The terms beyond $k=x-\frac 1 2+O(\frac 1 x)$ don't seem to be correct because of the error of Stirling's approximation. You can get an "exact" expression for $k$ in terms of polygamma function: $\psi_0(k+1)=\log x$ by directly differentiating $\frac {x^k}{\Gamma(k+1)}$. $\psi_0(x)=\log x-\frac 1 {2x}-\frac 1 {12x^2}+O(\frac 1 {x^3})$ yields $-\frac {1}{24}$ as $\frac 1 {x^2}$ coefficient in asymptotics of $k(x)$.

Comment: @A.S.. I fully agree with you. I think it would be interesting you write an answer in such a spirit. Cheers.

Comment: It's not really worth it since strictly speaking we are looking for an *integer* $k$. Since $T(k=x-1)=T(k=x)$, we immediately get integer maximizer $k=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and a continuous maximizer $k=x-\frac 1 2+o(1)$ with a tiny bit more work. Any additional terms seem to be answering a significantly different question. I wanted to point out that higher-order asymptotics at a later stage (Lambert's) is bound to be wrong given a lower-order asymptotics (Stirlings) earlier on. Cheers.

Comment: @A.S.. I cannot do anything else beside claiming that  I totally agree ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Since I am not allowed to use Lambert function, I used Newton procedure. The answer remains the same right? still k ≈ x-1/2